# How do I display more characters when debugging SFDX code?

Tags: vs-code, sfdx-plugin, apex-replay-debugger

I have variable in my code defined as follows:

```
String myString = myConfig.my_field_name__c;
```

When debugging in the SFDX console (in VS Code), the variable's value is only displayed as:

```
myString: 'https://myUrl.abc.defg (15 more) ...'
```

... and there doesn't seem to be any way to see what those 15 additional characters are.  Does anyone know how to see this information?

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `System.debug(myString);` in your code the entire string should be displayed.